# Show Dialog Question

Tags: c#

How can I get the Xwinnerform to stay on top an keep the main form from being clicked, I tried ShowDialog but I cant get it to work.

```
 static public bool CheckWinner(Button[] myControls)
            {
                //bolean statement to check for the winner 
                bool gameOver = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    int a = Winners[i, 0];
                    int b = Winners[i, 1];
                    int c = Winners[i, 2];

                    Button b1 = myControls[a], b2 = myControls[b], b3 = myControls[c];
                    if (b1.Text == "" || b2.Text == "" || b3.Text == "")
                        continue;
                    if (b1.Text == b2.Text && b2.Text == b3.Text)
                    {
                        xWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
                        xWinnerForm.ShowDialog(b1.Text + " is the Winner");

                    }



                }


                       return gameOver;
            }
        enter code here
```

Comment: "... can't get it to work" is too vague. What doesn't work?

Comment: Could you explain "can't get it to work?"  ShowDialog is the appropriate method.

Comment: it says The best overloaded method match for 'name' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You comment indicates that Thomas's answer is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overload of `ShowDialog` that accepts a string. As was suggested to you in another question, do not use the `Show` (or `ShowDialog`) method to populate the value of a label. Either create a property on your form that gets and sets the text of the label or create a function that sets it, then just call `ShowDialog(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a `MessageBox`

```
MessageBox.Show(b1.Text + " is the Winner");
```

Comment: I had one in there but the project requires a from to be called through a class

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to pass the parent form as an argument to [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx):

```
xWinnerForm.ShowDialog(mainForm);
```

Since you are passing it a `string`, I'm guessing that you overloaded `ShowDialog` in `xWinnerForm`. Add an overload that also accepts the `IWin32Window` parameter and passes it on to the base class method. Or better yet, do not overload `ShowDialog`, but pass the window text to the `xWinnerForm()` constructor instead.

Comment: I'm new to this could you give me a clearer example if its not to much trouble